# What is the best way to check if a website folder exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I need to check if a folder exists within an ASP.NET website. This is to be done within the website itself and I need to check a few folders so want to make sure there is little overhead (ie no WebCLient calls etc)

My thinking is that I could do a HttpServerUtility.MapPath("~/") to get the root path and then a Directory.Exists(rootPath + webPath) to check the folders. Would this work for Server Farms assuming the folder structures are the same?

Is this the best way or is there some equavalent yo WebDirectory.Exists(~/mysite/somepath)

All comments welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using System.IO;


`if (Directory.Exists (Server.MapPath("~/Views/Common/")))

{

//Stuff

}`

Comment: Server.MapPath is exactly what I've needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool folderExists = Directory.Exists(@"c:\windows");
```